# How can I get the markdown content of an accepted answer with the StackExchange API?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I'm trying to get the markdown body of an accepted answer making this request:

https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/search/advanced?accepted=True&title=length%20undefined&is_answered=True&site=stackoverflow

Comment: `accepted_answer_id`

Comment: Already have that. But how to get the text? What request should I make?

Comment: For example, should I use /answer/{accepted_answer_id}? I want to get the contents of it in markdown syntax.

Comment: That's irrelevant, but I'm using Python's requests module. Already fixed this, let me create a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the question id(s), you need to make a GET request to `/questions/{ids}` and get the `accepted_answer_id` property. Then, make another GET request to `/answers/{ids}` using the answer id you already have. With an appropriate [filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters), you can extract the body of an answer as markdown (**`body_markdown`**) or as HTML (`body`).

Here is the Python code:

```python
from stackapi import StackAPI

question_id = 54428242 # a random question
sitename = "stackoverflow"
# only include accepted_answer_id
question_filter = "!9bOY8fLl6"
# only include body and body_markdown
answer_filter = "!-)QWsboN0d_T"

SITE = StackAPI(sitename)
question = SITE.fetch("questions/{ids}",
                      ids = question_id,
                      filter = question_filter)
accepted_answer_id = question["items"][0]["accepted_answer_id"]
answer = SITE.fetch("answers/{ids}",
                    ids = accepted_answer_id,
                    filter = answer_filter)

answer_info = answer["items"][0]
print("Answer's HTML body: ",answer_info["body"])
print("Answer's markdown body: ", answer_info["body_markdown"])
```

The code uses the [StackAPI](https://github.com/AWegnerGitHub/stackapi) library ([docs](https://stackapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)). You might also have noticed that I use filters to limit the return object's properties to the ones I need (and only those). I suggest you do the same.

See:

- [What is the right way to create a Stack Exchange API filter?](https://stackapps.com/q/4155)
- [How can I create a filter from scratch using filter/create?](https://stackapps.com/q/4973)
- [**Some fields' names** - included in the `default` filter](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/read-filter#filters=default&filter=default&run=true)
- [How can I use custom filters in the Stack Exchange API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65687547)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using this request:
[https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/answers/{answer_id}?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/answers/%7Banswer_id%7D?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&filter=withbody)

---

> Note that `withbody` is not a HTML tag, it [`is default plus the *.body fields`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters#:%7E:text=withbody%2C%20which%20is%20default%20plus%20the%20*.body%20fields). If you just use `body_markdown` in the above API url, you will only get the `body_markdown` in the result and none of the default values.

Comment: `withbody` is in HTML tag. It is `body_markdown` which allows to have the result in markdown. https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=264298&filter=!xR5eaP-zsOwr)EDJhA&site=meta&run=true

Comment: Thanks! When I asked this question 4 years ago, I really don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: As I answer you, I am in March 2023. The question was asked a year and a half ago. Are you in the future? Has ChatGPT finally taken our jobs like detroit become human?

Comment: I can't answer that question. *Kid, turn on the machine! We're going back in time!*

Comment: `withbody` is not a HTML tag, it [`is default plus the *.body fields`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters#:~:text=withbody%2C%20which%20is%20default%20plus%20the%20*.body%20fields)